# Ошибка при конвертации, проблема не решена

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных, json

Есть программа, переводящая базу данных в описание json
Выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "D:\FolderTask\dbtojson.py", line 153, in <module>
    f.write(s) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters
in position 95-100: ordinal not in
range(128)
```

Что эта за ошибка и в чем ее причина?
Прогамма следующая:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#eclipse + pydev
import json,sqlite3,collections,scripts_revert

con = sqlite3.connect('borey.db')
sql = con.cursor()
sql_f = con.cursor()
sql_c = con.cursor()
sql_c_d = con.cursor()
sql_i = con.cursor()

js = {}
#
sql.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_DOMAINS)

js_domains = []
for domain in sql:
    js_domain = collections.OrderedDict([])
    js_domain['name'] = domain[0]
    js_domain['type'] = domain[1]
    if domain[2] != None:
        js_domain['length'] = domain[2]
    if domain[3] != None:
        js_domain['precision'] = domain[3]
    js_domains.append(js_domain)
js['domains'] = js_domains
#
sql.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_TABLES)

js_tables = []
for table in sql:
    js_table = collections.OrderedDict([])
    js_table['name'] = table[1]
    js_table['description'] = table[2]
    table_id = table[0]
    #поля
    sql_f.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_FIELDS,(table_id,))
    
    js_fields = []
    for field in sql_f:
        js_field = collections.OrderedDict([])
        js_field['name'] = field[0]
        js_field['description'] = field[1]
        if field[4] == None:
            js_field['type'] = field[3]
            if field[5] != None:
                js_field['length'] = field[5]
            if field[6] != None:
                js_field['precision'] = field[6]
        else:
            js_field['domain'] = field[4]
        if field[2] == 'True':
            js_field['props'] = ['required']
        js_fields.append(js_field)        
    js_table['fields'] = js_fields
    #print(js_fields)
    #print(' ')
    #ограничения
    sql_c.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_CONSTR,(table_id,))

    js_constraints = []
    js_constraint = collections.OrderedDict([])
    print(sql_c)
    for constraint in sql_c:
        js_constraint = collections.OrderedDict([])
        js_constraint['name'] = constraint[1]
        js_constraint['type'] = constraint[2]
        constraint_id = constraint[0]
        
        sql_c_d.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_CONSTR_DET,(constraint_id,))
        js_constraint_details = []
        for constraint_detail in sql_c_d:
            js_constraint_details.append(constraint_detail[0])
        js_constraint['items'] = js_constraint_details
        if constraint[2] == 'FOREIGN':
            js_constraint['reference'] = constraint[3]
        js_constraints.append(js_constraint)
    if js_constraint != {}:
        js_table['constraints'] = js_constraints
    #индексы
    
    sql_i.execute(scripts_revert.SEL_IND,(table_id,))

    js_indices = []
    js_index = {}
    for index in sql_i:
        js_index = collections.OrderedDict([])
        js_index['name'] = index[0]
        js_index['items'] = [['field',index[1]]]
        js_indices.append(js_index)
    if js_index != {}:
        js_table['indices'] = js_indices    
    #
    js_tables.append(js_table)
js['tables'] = js_tables
#
#js = json.dumps(js,indent=3,ensure_ascii=False) #indent - смещение табуляции
#json.dump(js, open('semen-revert.json', 'w'),indent=3,ensure_ascii=False)

#print(js)

indent = '   '
indent2 = indent + indent
indent3 = indent2 + indent
indent4 = indent3 + indent

s = ''
s +='{ \n'
#domains
if 'domains' in js:
    s += indent + '"domains" : [' + '\n'
    for domain in js['domains']:
        s += indent2 + json.dumps(domain,ensure_ascii=False) + ',\n'
    s = s[0:-2] + '\n'
    s += indent + '],\n'
#tables
s += indent + '"tables" : [' + '\n'
for table in js['tables']:
    s += indent2 + '{\n'
    s += indent3 + '"name" : "' + table['name'] + '", "description" : "' + table['description'] + '",\n'
    #
    s += indent3 + '"fields" : [\n'
    for field in table['fields']:
        s += indent4 + json.dumps(field,ensure_ascii=False) + ',\n'
    s = s[0:-2] + '\n'
    s += indent3 + ']'
    #
    if 'constraints' in table:
        s += ',\n'
        s += indent3 + '"constraints" : [\n'
        for constr in table['constraints']:
            s += indent4 + json.dumps(constr,ensure_ascii=False) + ',\n'
        s = s[0:-2] + '\n'
        s += indent3 + ']'
    #
    if 'indices' in table:
        s += ',\n'
        s += indent3 + '"indices" : [\n'
        for index in table['indices']:
            s += indent4 + json.dumps(index,ensure_ascii=False) + ',\n'
        s = s[0:-2] + '\n'
        s += indent3 + ']\n'
    else:
        s += '\n'
    #
    s += indent2 + '},\n'
s += indent + ']\n'
#
s +='}'

#print(s)
f = open('semen-revert.json','w')
f.write(s)
f.close()

con.close()
print('okay')
```

Действительно, json содержит русские символы и для этого в json.dumps используется опция ensure_ascii=False. Пока что приведенный советы @qnub (unicode(s) и замена на f = open('semen-revert.json','wb') не дали результатов. Жду еще ответов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо в итоге s имеет тип 'unicode' (можно проверить, сказав type(s)). Поэтому, чтобы ее записать надо выбрать кодировку. Делается это методом encode:

```
f.write(s.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Программа ожидает, что строки будут в ASCII кодировке, а получает в чём-то другом. Возможно в UTF-8 или Windows-1251.

Comment: В коде есть строки json.dumps(.....,ensure_ascii=False), значит, надо из них убрать ensure_ascii.

Comment: [Врядле](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=json.dumps#json.dumps). Судя по тексту ошибка в 153 строке файла Taskdbtojson.py. Там какая-то функция получает строку не состоящую из ASCII символов.

Comment: @qnub я привел текст программы, не могли бы посмотреть

Comment: 4-я строка снизу ```f.write(s)``` вызывает ошибку потому что переменная 's' не ASCII. возможно (скорее всего) какие-то из переменных составивших её содержат не латинские символы. Попробуйте заменить на ```f.write(unicode(s))```

Comment: или ранее ```f = open('semen-revert.json','w')``` на ```f = open('semen-revert.json','wb')```

Comment: Вообще часть кодирования данных в json сильно усложнена, достаточно было собрать словарь и выполнить ```json.dumps``` над ним.

Comment: попробовал сделать оба варианта изменений, но выскакивает все та же ошибка

Answer (score 0):

1. Прочтите
       http://www.rupy.ru/static/files/07/02/12/rupyru2007-yurevich-unicode-thesis.pdf
2. Проверьте тип s
3. Пишите в файл например так:

> ```
> from codecs import open
> with open('semen-revert.json', mode='w', encoding='utf8') as p:
>     p.write(s)
> ```